# How to add Marker in google maps from leaflet geocoder

Tags: angular, google-maps, leaflet, geocoding, google-maps-urls

I am using `leaflet-geosearch` to search for longitude and latitude of an address which I show display in a google maps page, i am using angular

in my component

```
private openAddressInMap() {
    this.provider.search({query: address}).then(result => { // search coordinates for each city
      if (!isNullOrUndefined(result) && result.length > 0 && !isNullOrUndefined(result[0])) {
        const lng = result[0].x;
        const lat = result[0].y;
        window.open('https://maps.google.com/?q=' + lat + ',' + lng, '_blank');
      }
    });
}
```

then I open google maps link by passing lat and lng, the problem is the marker is not well positionned, it points on the wrong address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need get coordinates via geocoder? If you use [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action), you can directly send address as a `query` parameter of URL and avoid geocoding request

The code snippet is

```
private openAddressInMap() {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' + encodeURIComponent(address), '_blank');
}
```

Try for example the following URL:

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=New+York

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's what I finished doing and it works like a miracle